# Can I install additional encodings in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, encoding, utf-8, cp1252

I have the issue, that I need to use a subversion repository that was created (and is still in use) under windows. Thus the default encoding is `CP-1252`.

Now I want to checkout this repository in linux and alter files there using eclipse. I do not want to reencode the whole file using `iconv` to `UTF-8` if possible as I do not know how good the programs under windows will behave.

My first idea was to set the project encoding to `CP-1252`. Under my installation (Kepler under linux) of eclipse there is no option `CP-125x` for the encoding. Only some `UTF-*` and `ISO-8859-1` is selectable.

Is there a way to install further encodings in eclipse?

Comment: The drop down only shows the common encodings, you can type in a encoding name in the text field - anything that the Java `Charset` class supports.

Comment: Looks like `Charset` uses the name 'windows-1252' for this encoding

Comment: Thanks a lot! If you write it as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'Text file encoding' field on the 'Preferences > General > Workspace' page only shows the most common encodings in the drop-down. However you can type in other encodings in to field. Any encoding that is supported by the Java `Charset` class is accepted.

The Windows 'CP-125x' encodings are called 'windows-125x' by `Charset`.

The same applies to file encodings shown in the file 'Properties > Resource' page.