# Eclipse does not find MacRoman

Tags: eclipse, macos, encoding, osx-yosemite

I just updated the Mac to the latest Yosemite, and downloaded Java 8 JDK 8u40 Build b09.

The projects are all encoded in MacRoman but Eclipse does not give me that option of enconding.

Is this from the java version or is there something I can download to make Eclipse encode in MacRoman again?

Comment: You can type MacRoman in to the encoding field, the drop down list just shows the most common encodings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I install additional encodings in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954743/can-i-install-additional-encodings-in-eclipse)

Comment: thanks @greg-449 idk how to handle duplicate questions, if you make an answer it I'll make sure to accept it.

Comment: For duplicates you just vote up the original answer. This question will eventually be closed as a duplicate but can still help people searching with a similar problem.